Is there any standard way of parsing RFC3339 compliant dateTime instead of using patterns in java?
Is there any standard way of parsing RFC3339 compliant dateTime instead of using patterns in java ?
It seems there isn't one. I tried finding solution over the internet but most of them were using patterns for parsing RFC3339 compliant dateTime values.

Java doesn't even support ISO 8601 fully. What format are your dates actually coming in (irrespective of standard number)?

If you’re talking about this format, OffsetDateTime’s parse and toString methods already do this.  No DateTimeFormatter is needed.

In what formatting pattern are you interested?

What is the problem with using patterns?

All of the examples in section 5.8 of RFC 3339 can be parsed with DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME. Which are the RFC 3339 date-time strings that you want to parse and cannot parse with that formatter?

RFC 3339 by The Internet Society is a self-described “profile” of the ISO 8601. But ISO does not provide for profiles. And the RFC makes some screwy unwise contradictions of ISO 8601.
So, I suggest you forget about the RFC. Focus instead on ISO 8601, nicely documented on Wikipedia.
The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text. No need for you to define a formatting pattern.
You neglected to mention the specific format of interest. Several are predefined as constants on the DateTimeFormatter class.
Perhaps you meant the format for a date with time as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. For that, use Instant class. The Z on the end is an abbreviation for an offset of zero, +00:00.
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2007-12-03T10:15:30.1764435Z" ) ;
String output = instant.toString() ;  // Produces: 2007-12-03T10:15:30.1764435Z

Those methods are using the constant DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT formatter object.
